# how to http post from localhost node server to another port?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, port

Hi I have node running on server 8080 on an ec2 box.

I have gandalf (https://gandalf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) running on port 5000 on that same ec2 box.

how might I send a post request from node to

```
request.post({
    uri: "http://localhost:5000/user/",
        form: {
        name: username,
        keys: {
            keyname: ssh_string
        }
        },
    }, function(error, response, body) {
});
```

I get a 404 error. Anyone guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 means you were able to contact the other server but the page you requested was not found so you should check your other server.